# Linear evolution equation $u'(t)=A(t,\omega)u(t)$ with time-dependent random operator

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, operator-theory

I have had some previous knowledge on evolution equations in a Banach space of the form $$u'(t)=Au(t),$$ where $A$ generates some strongly continuous operator semigroup. Now I am looking at a problem where randomness and dependence upon time are introduced to $A$.

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $X$ be a Banach space. For each $\omega$ in $\Omega$ and each time $t$, let $A(\omega, t)$  be a linear operator on $X$ that is the generator of a strongly continuous semigroup. For each $\omega$ in $\Omega$, we have a linear evolution equation $$u_{\omega}'(t)=A(\omega,t)u_\omega(t),\  u_\omega(0)=u_0$$ where $u_0$ in $X$ is deterministic. (And for the problem to make sense, let us assume that $u_0$ is in the domain $D(A(\omega, 0))$ for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$.)

I would like to learn about the more general problem, though in my specific problem, $$A(\omega,t)=A_0+A_1(t)+A_2(\omega),$$ where $A_0$ is fixed, $A_1$ depends on $t$ but not on $\omega$ and $A_2$ depends on $\omega$ but not on $t$.

Surely such problem have been studied. Does anyone know some good textbooks/lecture notes on this topic?

Secondly, I have a more specific question. Suppose there exists an interval $I$ such that for each $\omega$, the solution $u_\omega(t)$ exists and is unique for all time $t$ in $I$. Then I may view the solutions $u_\omega(t)$ as a function $u:\Omega \rightarrow  C^1(I,X)$ that maps each $\omega$ to the $C^1$ path $(t\mapsto u_\omega(t))$ in $X$. With some suitable norm, and hence a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $C^1(I,X)$, what can be said about the measurability of this function $u:\Omega \rightarrow  C^1(I,X)$?